# VBA Insertion of a row ignores hidden columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have code to insert row at selection with predefined formulas and formatting of row above. However, before insertion, some of the columns might be hidden, and when insertion is performed, all formatting in a new row is offset due to hidden columns.

Currently I found the temporary solution - before insertion I expand all hidden columns.

Is there a method to simply avoid offsetting and paste formatting in **all cells**, including hidden ones, without expanding hidden columns?

```
Range("A:BH").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrAbove
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

'then goes code to insert formulas in each cell
```

Comment: If you know specifically what formats you want to copy (e.g. font, color of interior, borders) you could copy those specific formats in a way that bypasses copy/paste-special entirely. What you are doing now seems reasonable. As a tweak, you could 1) turn off screen-updating, 2) construct a range consisting of currently hidden columns, 3) unhide them, 4) do your thing, 5) rehide them, 6) turn screen updating back on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution developed on the basis of **John Coleman**'s comment (but I still have a feeling there should be more elegant solution, something like `IncludeHiddenRows = True` when copying formats):

```
    Dim n As Variant
    Dim HidRange As Range
    Dim HidCol As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For n = 1 To 182 'make a snapshot (=HidRange) of currently hidden columns
        Set HidCol = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("tests2").columnS(n)
        If HidCol.Hidden = True Then
            If HidRange Is Nothing Then
                Set HidRange = HidCol
            Else
                Set HidRange = Union(HidCol, HidRange)
            End If
        End If
    Next n

    If Not HidRange Is Nothing Then 'Unhide the hidden columns
        HidRange.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If

    'perform copying formats etc.

    If Not HidRange Is Nothing Then 'Return to initial state
        HidRange.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```